# Look up value in a matrix based on the strings in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data frame like

```
 X     Y    VALUE    
"AAA" "BBB"
"CCC" "AAA"
```

I also have a matrix as:

```
     AAA BBB CCC
 AAA  1   13  2
 BBB  27  11  4
 CCC  6   12  3
```

with AAA, BBB and CCC as the column names and row names. How can I fill the VALUE column in my data frame with the values in the matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
df$VALUE <- mat[cbind(df$X, df$Y)]
```

Using your example:

```
df <- data.frame(X = c("AAA", "CCC"),
                 Y = c("BBB", "AAA"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
#     X   Y
# 1 AAA BBB
# 2 CCC AAA

mat <- matrix(c(1, 27, 6, 13, 11, 12, 2, 4, 3),
              nrow = 3, ncol = 3,
              dim = list(c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC"),
                         c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC")))
mat
#     AAA BBB CCC
# AAA   1  13   2
# BBB  27  11   4
# CCC   6  12   3

df$VALUE <- mat[cbind(df$X, df$Y)]
df
#     X   Y VALUE
# 1 AAA BBB    13
# 2 CCC AAA     6
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. For some reason, the strings are stored as rownames and colnames in my matrix, and directly use "cbind" does not work correctly for my matrix. I have to use something like mat[cbind(match(m3$X,rownames(mat)),match(m3$Y,colnames(mat)))] to make it work.

Comment: by "does not work", do you mean it does not return the expected values (but no error)? If so, the problem could come from the fact that your X and Y columns are factors, you can check that by running `class(m3$X)`.

Comment: ...in which case you could run something a little shorter like  `mat[cbind(as.character(m3$X), as.character(m3$Y))]`, or consider removing factors from your data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the dataframe directly from the matrix with melt:

```
library(reshape2)
melt(mat)
```

Comment: This would be the answer to a different question. You are not using one of the OP's two inputs.